# AWS SES sending email, but crashing right after

Tags: php, html, amazon-web-services

```
try {
        $ses_result = $client->sendRawEmail(
                array(
            'RawMessage' => array(
                'Data' => $msg
            )
                ), array(
            'Source' => $from,
            'Destinations' => $to_str
                )
        );
        //email is sent properly, but crashes at this point sending an error 500 (php)
        if ($ses_result) {
            $res->message_id = $ses_result->get('MessageId');
        } else {
            $res->success = false;
            $res->result_text = "Amazon SES did not return a MessageId";
        }
}
```

This part of the code using AWS SES crashes RIGHT AFTER sending the email, it is sent properly, but right at the part I put the comment it crashes and sends an error 500. The documentation is not really helpful on this, as all it says is the following:

> InternalFailure
>   The request processing has failed because of an unknown error, exception or failure.
>
> HTTP Status Code: 500

I was wondering if anyone has experienced something like this or if I could get some help.

**update:** this is what I'm getting after enabling error displaying:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'SimpleXMLElement' not found in /var/www/html/xillingo-2.0/assets/aws/Aws/Api/Parser/PayloadParserTrait.php:39 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/xillingo-2.0/assets/aws/Aws/Api/Parser/QueryParser.php(44): Aws\Api\Parser\QueryParser->parseXml(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream)) #1 /var/www/html/xillingo-2.0/assets/aws/Aws/WrappedHttpHandler.php(126): Aws\Api\Parser\QueryParser->__invoke(Object(Aws\Command), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response)) #2 /var/www/html/xillingo-2.0/assets/aws/Aws/WrappedHttpHandler.php(93): Aws\WrappedHttpHandler->parseResponse(Object(Aws\Command), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Array) #3 /var/www/html/xillingo-2.0/assets/aws/GuzzleHttp/Promise/Promise.php(203): Aws\WrappedHttpHandler->Aws{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response)) #4 /var/www/html/xillingo-2.0/assets/aws/GuzzleHttp/Promise/Promise.php(156): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::callHandler(1, Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Array) #5 /var/www/html/xillingo-2.0/assets/aws/GuzzleH in /var/www/html/xillingo-2.0/assets/aws/Aws/Api/Parser/PayloadParserTrait.php on line 39

**update2:** nvm... i went full retard... solved it...

Comment: What is `$res`? It is most likely NULL.

Comment: it doesnt even get to that point, it crashes right where i put the comment at, tried printing something and adding a die(); and it doesnt even do that.